# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfcs140d.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, linker-errors, visual-studio-2019

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfcs140d.lib' i got this error when i debug my program how to fix this issue....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXYQ6.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Looks like you are linking against static debug library for MFC 14.0. Why are you using MFC at all? It's a console application, you probably don't need it. Create a new C++ console project and don't use MFC as you probably don't have the package installed via Visual Studio.

Comment: @Andy if he don't have MFC installed, i think he can not create a MFC project because VS will not offer him this option

Comment: According to the .png, you are createing a C++ console project. As far as I'm concerned, the console program does not require mfcs140d.lib. I'm appreciate that if you could provide us the specific steps to reproduce the issue, We will provide you with better help.